# Existing or New Customer on Checkout Success

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-session

We have some affiliate tracking on our site.  On the success page we need to pass the tracking some information including whether it's a new or returning customer.
I've tried a few things but I can't seem to get it working.

My latest attempt is the following

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
  # Existing Customer
  $ED = 11111;
}

else {
  # New customer
  $ED = 22222;
}
```

This script just returns everybody is a new customer.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: where did you insert this code? Anyway you will not see with this if it is a new or returning customer, but only if the customer has an account and is logged in. The account could have been created also in the actual session

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$pidsess = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$custsess = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if($custsess->isLoggedIn() == true) {
 $LoggedIn = 'yes';
}
unset($piddata);
unset($custsess);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()` does not return if the customer is a returning customer is or not. As the function suggests, it returns only true if a customer **is logged in**.

In order to see if someone is a returning customer you would have to make a module where you track who has visited your site before by either logging for example their IP address and/or useragent or by placing a cookie in their browser.